# DOMPDF 0.5.1 - Fonts not working on live Server

Tags: php, fonts, dompdf

I've got DOMPDF 0.5.1 running in a Drupal implementation on my localhost (xampp, windows 7) which generates my Pdf's just fine. 
But when i commit this to the live server things go wrong. I get the error: "The font "Futura" contains a bad /BBox"
And all text is displayed as dots.

Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Obvious question: are you using the same font file or are you relying on the server's font directory?

Comment: yes, i'm using the same font file. The path to the font directory on the server is the same as on my localhost.

Comment: perheps is only the path, make some ajustment and probably everything will be fine. I'm using DOMPDF and everything is going fine, local and remote.. only certify the path is right.

Comment: Have you tried asking this on the dompdf mailing list? It's quite a specialist subject so you may get more luck there than on the generic Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The user who starts your webserver i.e. httpd or apache must have read/write access to the font folder as well, that might cause the problem.

> Give your webserver write permission on the path specified in DOMPDF_FONT_DIR (lib/fonts by default). Under *nix, ideally you can make the webserver group the owner of this directory and give the directory group write permissions. For example, on Debian systems, Apache runs as the www-data user:
>
> $ chgrp www-data lib/fonts
>
> $ chmod g+w lib/fonts
>
> If your user is not a member of the www-data group or you do not have root privileges, you can make the directory world writable and set the sticky bit:
>
> $ chmod 1777 lib/fonts

http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Installation